# Most efficient way to pick unique strings from weighted categories

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

**The setup:**

- n categories
- each category has a weight (an artificial number that indicates the importance of that category)
- Each string is globally unique

**Example:**

- **Categories:** a, b, c
- **Strings:**

  - a_001, a_002, a_003
  - b_001, b_002, b_003
  - c_001, c_002, c_003
- **Weights:**

  - a: 1
  - b: 2
  - c: 1

**The task:**

Get an array of unique strings, 1 from category a, 2 from category b and 1 from category c. The number of picked strings from a category doesn't have to exactly line up with the weightedNumber. The weights should just be considered (strongly though) while picking the strings. However, if it's not possible, then it's not the end of the world. The number of strings picked total however, MUST be correct.

**The problems:**

- The weight could be 10, but there are only 3 unique strings in that category (in that case, it should be filled up with strings from the other categories based on their weights)
- I'm working with firestore, so I can only pick one random string at a time and I don't have access to the number of strings in a given category

**My attempt:**

```
function pickStrings(numberOfStrings, arrCategories) {
  // Calculates the weight of each category
  // Sets initial weight and stringsleft to weightTotal and numberOfStrings
  // Iterates over the categories:
  //    selectedStrings.push(...pickStringsFromCategory(calculatedNumberBasedOnWeight, categoryId))
  // returns selectedStrings
}

function pickStringsFromCategory(numberOfStrings, categoryid) {
  // Create a map of picked strings
  // Randomly pick a string from that category
  // Checks if the string was picked already
  // Tries again (up to 10 times) if the string was already picked
}
```

However, that just doesn't feel right. Trying 10 times is an artificial number and if the category with only 1 string and weightedNumber of 10 is the last one, the number of strings picked is less than the numberOfStrings.

Any ideas on how to improve this algorithm?

Comment: please put the data into a data structure. -  and add some examples.

Comment: The problem is, there is no real data structure. All I have available to me is "getRandomStringFromCategory()" which pulls a random string directly from the database and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible approach:

```js
var arr = [
  ["a_001", "a_002", "a_003"],
  ["b_001", "b_002", "b_003"],
  ["c_001", "c_002", "c_003"]
];

var weights = [7, 2, 1];

var str = "";
weights.map((o, i) => {

  let curr = i;
  let p = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < o; j++) {
    if (arr[curr][p]) {//this could be and ajax, function, whatever
      str += arr[curr][p] + " ";//this is an assumption
      p++;
    } else { //this happens when we didn't find a string into such category 
      curr = curr + 1; //we move one category
      p = 0;//firs element in the next category
      j--;//move back because we didn't finish
    }
  }

})

console.log(str);
```